# Reference Data tables referential integrity

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a few reference tables, i.e. AuditType, StatusType, etc. These tables contain standard ENUM data. My intention is to rebuild the data of these tables everytime I deploy my database changes, i.e. these tables are not identity enabled.

However, these tables can have foreign key relation to some other transaction tables. **The issue** is that, while I am trying to rebuild the data in those (reference) tables, I cannot drop the data as they are already referenced.

Is it correct to have a foreign key relation in the transaction table(s)? If not how else can I handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are those reference table having static data?

Comment: what do you mean by static data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the foreign key references backwards -- or are at least describing them backwards.  The transaction table should have foreign key references to the reference tables, using the primary key.

You should populate these tables at database creation, and then use `insert` and `delete` to make changes.

Once the foreign keys are in place, the database will enforce *relational integrity*.  That normally means that the database validates that values in the transaction table reference correct rows.  This is a good thing.  It is the "C" in the ACID properties of databases.

So, if you want to make changes, do not delete the data there.  Use `insert` to add new rows.

Comment: Gordons solution will pay off in unmeasurable benefit to you over the years.  In this situation you often you find it is the compiled client code that actually owns the enum.  That is why it can never change even if it is easy to do in the DB.

Comment: One other caveat to keep in mind is that if you have a stored proc that is loading up the transaction table with the enums but you really do not own the enums then you may have to auto insert at runtime the new enum into the parent table to accept the transaction.  This is often the case where your transaction table is really a log of already completed transactions so you would rather get the actual transaction recorded instead of having it fail from ref integrity standpoint because the enum is missing.

Comment: @Gordon, Thanks a ton for the answer, I am sorry it was the way I explained the whole thing, the references are actually how you mentioned them, the transaction table actually have the foreign keys to the reference tables. 

I am so glad with the answer you came up with and it actually changed (in a good way) the way I look at a few other things as well.